# Monitor cutting out from time to time

Tags: multiple-monitors, 21.04, wayland, amdgpu, scaling

I've been using Ubuntu as my main OS for a while now, but there's one thing that really bothers me.

I'm using Ubuntu 21.04 with Wayland with fractional scaling. My main monitor, a Samsung U28D590D (via DisplayPort), frequently loses its signal for a few seconds and then reconnects again. The frequency of this happening seems random. Sometimes it doesn't happen for hours, other times it just cuts out a few times in a row. Different cables don't make a difference. This only happens with this one monitor and only under Ubuntu. When using Windows (any version really), it works without a problem. I've tried using X11 or any other version of Ubuntu, same thing. Different drivers, same thing. I think it might be a combination of my graphics card (Sapphire R9 290) and the way X/Wayland handles scaling (or maybe the monitor?).

Any suggestions?

Comment: I had the same with my Asus monitor and DisplayPort but not Wayland. After I had to re-purpose the cable to other device and switched to HDMI, it is not happening anymore. I would be curious to see any responses as well.

Comment: I would guess a cheap HDMI/DisplayPort cable is your problem. Windows has often just a better tolerance vs faulty hardware.

Comment: Could be, but I already tried 4 different DisplayPort cables, one of them cost me 35 € (and is only 50 cm long)...